# Parsing Twitter Search Results using PHP using XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, twitter, xmlreader

I'm using PHP curl to obtain an XML string for parsing and I'd like to parse with XMLReader.  I can't find any good examples of how to iterate through each of the entries while storing some of the nodes (user, title, updated) as variables.  Then I want to do something with the variables and move onto the next entry.  I also need to be able to check if a node is empty (to be able to identify which entries have geo data).

An example xml feed would look like [this](http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=twitter%20search).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a PHP client built for Twitter, such as - http://code.google.com/p/twitter-php/
Then you don't have to parse XML etc.

Using this library, your code for search page would look like

The search() method provides searching in twitter statuses:

```
    $results = $twitter->search('#nette');
```

The returned result is a PHP array:

```
    foreach ($results as $result) {
            echo "message: ", $result->text;
            echo "posted at " , $result->created_at;
            echo "posted by " , $result->form_user;
    }
```